Not working characters in Exec command of .desktop file
I just updated from ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 and have an issue with one of my existing *.desktop files. Inside the file I use a command which includes a '' character in the Exec declaration.
A minimum example is here:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=test
Exec=bash -c "echo \\"
Comment=test
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/gnome-remote-desktop.svg
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22

I get the error message: Failed to launche test. Desktop file didn't specify Exec field.
It works as soon as I replace the Exec Line with Exec=bash -c "echo hi"
Is this a breaking change from ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04? Or do I have to us a escape character?

This is actually mentioned in the Freedesktop specification for The Exec key (emphasis mine):

Note that the general escape rule for values of type string states
that the backslash character can be escaped as ("\") as well and that
this escape rule is applied before the quoting rule. As such, to
unambiguously represent a literal backslash character in a quoted
argument in a desktop entry file requires the use of four successive
backslash characters ("\\"). Likewise, a literal dollar sign in a
quoted argument in a desktop entry file is unambiguously represented
with ("\$").

So, given
$ cat test.desktop                                                                                          
[Desktop Entry]                                                                                                                                                             
Type=Application                                                                                                                                                            
Terminal=true
Name=test
Exec=bash -c "echo \\"
Comment=This is a test
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/gnome-remote-desktop.svg
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22

then desktop-file-validate complains:
$ desktop-file-validate test.desktop                                                                        
test.desktop: error: value "bash -c "echo \\"" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a quote which is not closed

(because it first applies the escape rule, turning \\ into \", then applies the quoting rule, making \" a literal quote instead of a closing quote) whereas the following
$ cat test.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=test
Exec=bash -c "echo \\\\"
Comment=This is a test
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/gnome-remote-desktop.svg
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22

passes desktop-file-validate without complaint.

Thanks to point to the desktop-file-validate tool. It works now with the right amount of escape characters \\
